# Taking out specific value from array with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, higher-order-functions, array-splice

Making a todo app, but got stucked at deleting specific value in array, what am i doing wrong and how should i correct it? splice acts same as shift method.

Also is there any other way or data structure that can be used for todo app.

```
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const todoInput = document.querySelector(".todoInput");
const list = document.querySelector(".renderListHere");

const todoList = [];

form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const text = todoInput.value.trim();

    if (text === "") {
        console.log("enter something");
    } else {
        addTodo(text);
        todoInput.value = "";
    }
});

const addTodo = (text) => {
    const todo = {
        id: Date.now(),
        text,
    };

    todoList.push(todo);
    renderTodo(todo);
};

const renderTodo = ({ text, id }) => {
    const li = document.createElement("li");

    li.classList.add("todoListItems");

    li.innerHTML = `
    <span> ${text} </span>
    <button id="${id}" class="del-btn"> x
    </button>
        `;

    list.append(li);
};

list.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if ((event.target.className = "del-btn")) {
        const arr = todoList.filter(
            (item) => item.id === parseInt(event.target.id)
        );
         todoList.splice(arr, 1);

    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML.

Comment: thanks for concern, figured it out, well as you are a web dev, i need to have a conversation with you sir.

Comment: prph8 What?....

Comment: about freelancing/job

Comment: Ask what you want to know.

Comment: so i need to ask you about how much experience is needed for applying to jobs, like how much of js, this is 4th montb of mine into web-dev.

Comment: You can start freelancing now but most jobs require more than `js` like *Node.js, React, Angular, Typescript, Etc..*(These all are not compulsory but at least one would be good)

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=javascript+developer&l=) for some idea.

Comment: i am into react now, done with basics soon will start building projects on it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the `filter` method.

The `Array.filter()` function returns a new array, so in your case, you could use:

```
todoList = todoList.filter(
   (item) => item.id !== parseInt(event.target.id)
);
```

So you are filtering `todoList` with only the items with id different than `event.target.id`, and applying the result to the same `todoList` variable.

Comment: thanks, i need to change array type to let from const and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const arr = todoList.filter(
        (item) => item.id !== parseInt(event.target.id)
    );
     
}
```

its return new array

you do not need splice()